# Multiple level relationship in the same table with two ids

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a table called `tbl_location` with fields `id,type,fk_id,name`

Now type here has values 
`0 = country`
`1 = state`
`2 = city`
`3 = area`

Now the area record will have id of city record as fk_id

And city record will have id of state as fk_id

And then state will have id of country as fk_id

And country will have 0/null as fk_id.

Now I want to know how do I join the records to fetch area, city, state and country.

**UPDATE**

On the basis of the type value I need to add the city, state, or country. That is if type is 3 add city, state and country.
or if it is 2 add state and country
or if it is 1 add country.

My model

```
<?php

namespace App\BackendModel;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Location extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    const ACTIVATE = 1;
    const DEACTIVATE = 0;

    CONST COUNTRY_TYPE = 0;
    CONST STATE_TYPE = 1;
    CONST CITY_TYPE = 2;
    CONST AREA_TYPE = 3;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'tbl_location';

    public function country(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\BackendModel\Location', 'id','fk_id')
        ->with('state')
        ->select('id', 'vchr_name','fk_id', 'int_type')
        ->where('int_type', COUNTRY_TYPE);
    }

    public function state(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\BackendModel\Location', 'id','fk_id')
        ->with('city')
        ->select('id', 'vchr_name','fk_id', 'int_type')
        ->where('int_type', STATE_TYPE);
    }

    public function city(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\BackendModel\Location', 'id','fk_id')
        ->select('id', 'vchr_name','fk_id', 'int_type')
        ->where('int_type', CITY_TYPE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at polymorphic relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: I am not sure thats what i wanted, but i was thinking that parameter grouping can help me do it but i have found something else as my answer but it can be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting I came up with this solution to my question, but i think it could have been better.

**Controller**

```
$location = Location::where('pk_int_location_id', $id)->pluck('int_type');
    switch ($location[0]) {
        case '3':
            $location = Location::with('city')->select('pk_int_location_id as area_id', 'vchr_name as area_name','fk_int_location_id', 'int_type')->where('pk_int_location_id', $id)->first();
            break;
        case '2':
            $location = Location::with('state')->select('pk_int_location_id as city_id', 'vchr_name as city_name','fk_int_location_id', 'int_type')->where('pk_int_location_id', $id)->first();
            break;
        case '1':
            $location = Location::with('country')->select('pk_int_location_id as state_id', 'vchr_name as state_name','fk_int_location_id', 'int_type')->where('pk_int_location_id', $id)->first();
            break;
        case '0':
            $location = Location::select('pk_int_location_id as country_id', 'vchr_name as country_name','fk_int_location_id', 'int_type')->where('pk_int_location_id', $id)->first();
            break;

        default:
            $location = Location::with('city', 'state', 'country')->where('pk_int_location_id', $id)->first();
            break;
    }
```

**Model**

```
public function country(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\BackendModel\Location', 'pk_int_location_id','fk_int_location_id')
    ->select('pk_int_location_id', 'vchr_name as country_name','fk_int_location_id', 'int_type')
    ->where('int_type', Location::COUNTRY_TYPE);
}

public function state(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\BackendModel\Location', 'pk_int_location_id','fk_int_location_id')
    ->with('country')
    ->select('pk_int_location_id', 'vchr_name as state_name','fk_int_location_id', 'int_type')
    ->where('int_type', Location::STATE_TYPE);
}

public function city(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\BackendModel\Location', 'pk_int_location_id','fk_int_location_id')
    ->with('state')
    ->select('pk_int_location_id', 'vchr_name as city_name','fk_int_location_id', 'int_type')
    ->where('int_type', Location::CITY_TYPE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Location::with('country', 'state', 'city')->get();` should make the job if you've set your relationships correctly

Comment: Updated my question please check

Comment: i know there is a possibility to check do that i am not getting where to check.